# Injection in test when using Angularjs & requirejs

Tags: testing, mocking, angularjs, requirejs, inject

I am trying to use AngularJS with RequireJS currently, but I do not know how to make the test work with injection.
Without RequireJS we could,

**Impl**

```
PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];  
var PhoneListCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 
    /* constructor body */ 
}];
```

**Test**

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
  $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
      respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  ctrl = $controller(PhoneListCtrl, {$scope: scope});
}));
```

However, when we use RequireJS we may define the controller as following,

demoController.js

```
define(["dependency"], function() {
    /* constructor body */ 
});
```

When using this controller, we add it as one of the dependencies and do not have a variable declaration.(Let me just use "Controller" as an example since we'd better call it "Service")

someJS.js

```
define(["demoController"], function(controller) {
     controller.method();
});
```

**My Question**
How can we inject the $http, $scope(or something else) to the target controller or service for testing when using RequireJS(AMD)?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work by following.

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep2', function              ($scope, dep2) {
    $scope.method = function () {//do something};
}]);
```

We can use this controller in test cases like this:

```
inject(function($controller, $rootScope, dep2) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        myController = $controller("MyController",
                {
                    $scope : scope,
                    dep2: dep2
                });
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar:

```
/*global define, document */

define(['angular', 'jquery'], function (angular, $) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        var myController = $controller('myController');
    };
});
```

The idea is that angular.bootstrap returns an injector, which allows you to fetch a service.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still don't know how to implement it. I mean I want to inject $httpBackend for testing, in this case how to use your example?

Comment: Hmm, i tried it myself with a fiddle, and couldn't solve it. Actually, I wouldn't bother to use requirejs for unit/e2e testing. Consider using [testacular](http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular/) however